# Reaction of alcohols with bromine

Tags: organic-chemistry, alcohols

In a reaction between $\ce{R-OH}$ and $\ce{Br2}$, what will the product be?
Initially I thought it would be $\ce{R-Br}$, but that doesn't seem right.

I'm oscillating between the product being either $\ce{R-OBr}$ or no reaction occurring at all. I've searched a bit on the web too, but couldn't get an answer.

What is the product?

Comment: $\ce{R-OBr}$ does not quite exist. [Another reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haloform_reaction) may be possible, though.

Comment: ROBr is actually  an reaction intermediate. See this: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ja00990a036

Comment: Also see this: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ja01176a069

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No reaction occurs with the reagents you have stated at room temperature. Maybe with different conditions (eg. basic conditions) the haloform reaction that Ivan commented would occur.